# Should I book with a Vueling flight although its previous flights have been canceled?

Tags: air-travel, spain, cancellations, vueling

I want to book with Vueling VY7475 flight on the 1st of September. however, its previous record isn't promising, its flight history [here](https://www.airportia.com/flights/vy7475/)  shows that all its flights have been canceled last year and didn't fly since, but their website says the flight on the 1st of September is scheduled.
All other flight options I have are 3 times higher the price!

Should I book with them? and How long before the scheduled flight, the airline informs its clients that the flight is cancelled?

Comment: You seem to understand the risk you're considering. We can't tell you whether you "should" book the cheap (but perhaps more likely to be cancelled) option or the more expensive (but perhaps more reliable) option. That's your decision to make.

Comment: I understand. If I booked with them, How long before the scheduled flight they would inform me if there is any cancellation? is there a certain requirement for airlines for that?

Comment: If they cancel within 2 weeks before the flight and don't rebook within a small window, they may have to pay you EU 261/2004 compensation (if you claim it) in addition to refunding the ticket. So waiting until 2 weeks before you fly would be one way to hedge your bets. Otoh, ticket prices will probably be higher at that time.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I book with them?

This really depends on your reason for travel and personal priorities.

> and How long before the scheduled flight, the airline informs its clients that the flight is cancelled?

Generally it's two weeks. Since it's an EU flight, they would owe you compensation if they cancel less than two weeks in advance so most will cancel only 15 days or so ahead even if they already know they won't fly.

Booking and refunding is still an interest free loan for them and many airlines have currently cash flow problems.

Comment: How likely is that an airline cancel a flight in within 15 days period, is it a big loss for them? Because the same flight is scheduled next week 5th of August, and 45 places out 75 places are already booked.